# Dynamically building static websites

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, gatsby

I'm building a simple website generator using React, Express/Node and MongoDB.
I built a UI to receive contents and styling params from a multi-step form, and a dashboard where users can manage settings in second place. All the data is saved/fetched in Mongo when needed, using Express. I have a "publish" button in the frontend, which fires a POST to the backend.

Then the related express route fetches the correct data from mongo and pass it to a function, which runs locally a "create-react-app" with a custom template and injects params/content to the right components. After that, it runs a build and deploys the result to a subdomain.

My question is: am I wrong managing to build static files and deploying them every single time the user hits the "publish" button?

Do I need to dynamically generate and serve the site when is requested?

Answer (score 0):

The best and most "react" way to do this would indeed be to dynamically generate and serve the site. It will be a bit more upfront work but will result in better ux.

What you are doing now will be quite slow and not very user friendly.

Comment: Would Next JS be the right solution then? Or there is a way to do it natively in React?

Comment: You can definitely do it natively in react -- just use react hooks / reducers to hold all the content/styling and then in the app pull that information in using the context api